# jQuery: Is it possible to temporarily disable/prevent certain dom elements from being selected/manipulated?

Tags: jquery

This will be a bit hard to explain but I am going to have to try my best.I have 3 hidden containers, which has 3 links that associates to each of the 3 containers via an ID.  And when i click each link it will open the container associated.

But now here is a twist.  There are other JS that will perform other actions which I have NO control to and they are NOT using any scope in their scripts so which means it is manipulating all 3 of my containers at once which is not the wanted behavior.  I want it to ONLY affect the container I clicked on.  So my first presumption is to somehow disable containers that are not opened from being modified and re-enable them when it is closed or I choose another container.  Confused yet?  Here is a sample link that should illustrate the setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/UxRkZ/1/

So as a summary, I want to somehow prevent the other hidden containers from being manipulated while one of the containers are visible/opened.  Remember there are other scripts that fires and those scripts have no scope as it thinks there should only be one container...

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on what the other mysterious script is doing, you could just detach the elements from the DOM if the mysterious script isn't caching them. Otherwise, there isn't much you can do short of modifying the mysterious script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what I ended up doing is iterate through all the divs and remove the class from each one and then re-applied them to the currently selected container only.  This way other JS scripts won't be able to manipulate those elements.

Answer (score 2):

You could give the elements that you don't want to be selected a class. Then filter out the results based on the specific class that you don't want to be included.

Below is an example of how to filter

```
var elems = $('selector').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).hasClass('noselect');
})
```

Comment: Perhaps the post wasn't clear.  Again I have no control over the scripts that performs some action.  I can only control the dom elements so I am trying to disable some containers so the other scripts don't even see it when one container is opened but need to restore it once, the container is closed or another one is opened.